# Better Memory Management in Python

Tags: python-2.7, memory, memory-management

I'm running a python script that reads in huge number of files and stores the content in lists and makes some comparisons. As expected, the amount of memory used is a lot. I've read about how it's not easy to make sure that the all memory allocated to lists, variables, etc, are deallocated and returned to the OS after `del` them.

What my script does is there is a folder of 99 files (each ~130MB), that I need to compare with another folder of ~12K files (each ~300KB). Right now, I divide the 12K files into batches of 200 each, and take each of the 99 files, compare it batch by batch, until all batches are done. Then take the next file of the 99 files, and repeat. After each batch, I'll try to free up memory by `del` the lists I'm done with, then do a `gc.collect()`.

When I look at my Windows Task Manager, I see the following:

```
Physical Memory (MB)
Total      3970
Cached     2665  <-- decreases slowly as more files are processed
Available  2612  <-- ranges from 2700+ to 2500+ in a cyclic manner as each batch is processed
Free       0     <-- ranges from 100+ to 0 in a cyclic manner as each batch is processed
```

The "Free memory" actually drops from ~2500MB when the PC is first booted up, to 0 while the script runs (the general trend is down, but it goes up by 100+ MB after each batch is processed), then it cycles from 0 to 100+ MB. I'm wondering if I should be worried about the "0 Free memory". Can I be do more to increase this "Free memory"?

Comment: Do you know if you are getting a slow-down because of page-file use? Memory is there to be used, and not having any 'free' memory space is not a bad thing, unless your system is moving memory onto disk (page-file). That said, 4GB is not a lot when you are running Windows and doing memory-intensive tasks as well.

Comment: Just to add to this - Available memory is what you need to worry about. Windows will pre-cache many things in an effort to speed up the OS, and will happily release this memory when an application needs it (such as your script). If the available memory starts hitting zero then you have a problem. Free memory being zero is pretty much normal.

Comment: The Paged value remains pretty consistent at 174MB. Thanks for putting my mind at ease about the zero "Free memory".